# Single Shortcut runs both as UAC Admin and UAC Non-Admin

Tags: windows-7, command-line, administrator

I would like a way to initiate a single command file - but that runs both with the full admin rights and the non-Admin token -

Either running as non-admin - and converting to admin - or running as admin and initiating a non-admin process would be fine

In particular I need to run the commands

```
SUBST E: G:\SUBST\E 
NET USE Y: \\SVR\PATH
```

both as an administrator and as a non-administrator

Built in stuff such as VBS, PS would be ok - I'm using Windows 7

I've the following batch file with RUNAS and confusingly it does not work at all - I also tried the direct runas /user:domain\usename /savecred "cmd /c subst" - I wrote the batch files to see what was happening

a1.bat

```
subst e: C:\Users\username\Documents\subst\e
subst
pause
```

A.bat

```
runas /user:domain\usename /savecred "cmd /c C:\Users\username\Documents\subst\E\a1.bat"
```

- If I run A1.bat in an Admin CMD THEN other admin CMD environments get the drive
- if I run A.bat in an Admin CMD THEN No admin CMDs except the temporary runas one gets the drive -including the original
- If I run A1.bat in a non-Admin cmd THEN other admin CMD get the drive
- if I run A.bat in a non-Admin cmd THEN no cmd environment gets the drive - except the temporary runas one

I have not tried with the NET USE commands

The background is that what I have found is that when I run

```
NET USE Y: \\SVR\PATH
```

without the administrative rights then I do not see the Y: drive when I later run a command with the administrative rights  - at the moment I just have two shortcuts on my desktop - which I double click - one which prompts for admin and one which does not - I need to double click the Admin one first as there at some programs which are single instance only , stay resident and need to run as admin.

I have a simple keyboard shortcut menu system which runs various commands when I press keycombinations - To make this portable I use a SUBST command to map my E: drive to a location.  As some of the commands need to be run as Administrator - the menu system needs the with admin and without admin environments to have the same drives mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are fine with built in **Windows** functions, I've provided a few batch file solutions below with the admin and non-admin operations I tested with **Windows 7**. Since you say you are prompted for admin, this solution will also prompt for the password of the/an admin credential to run it as with one having an option to save for future use after entering it the first time only.

---

### Batch File (Admin Prompted)

```
RUNAS /USER:<administrator> "CMD /C SUBST E: G:\SUBST\E" 
RUNAS /USER:<administrator> "CMD /C NET USE Y: \\SVR\PATH"
```

> **Note:** When you use this method, you have to type in the password of the administrator account you run the commands as per each time
>   these commands are run. You can use `CMD /K` here instead if you wish the elevated command prompt to stay up after running the commands.

[image]

**To Remove Saved Credentials**

In the **Run** dialog (<kbd>**`⊞`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`R`**</kbd>) type in `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` and press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd>. When the **Stored User Names and Passwords** windows opens up, you can highlight the credential(s) you want to delete which is(are) saved and then press the **Remove** option.

[image]

---

### Batch File (Admin with `/SaveCred`)

```
RUNAS /USER:<administrator> /SAVECRED "CMD /C SUBST E: G:\SUBST\E" 
RUNAS /USER:<administrator> /SAVECRED "CMD /C NET USE Y: \\SVR\PATH"
```

> **Note:** When you use this method, you have to type in the password of the administrator account *the first time you use it only* and then on subsequent runs when you specify the `/SAVECRED` switch you do not need to enter the password any longer. You can use `CMD /K` here instead if you wish the elevated command prompt to stay up after running the commands.

[image]

---

### Batch File (Non-Admin)

```
SUBST E: G:\SUBST\E 
NET USE Y: \\SVR\PATH
```

> **Note:** When you use this method, you are not prompted and basically you run as the non-elevated user you are signed onto the machine as
>   security context wise.

---

### Further Resources

- [Runas](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)
- [Cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: @Ross - I've written you an answer that I tested and confirmed works with Windows 7 as per my interpretation of all the detail you provided. So in total there are two different method to run admin elevated and the non-elevated is the same as you do that now for non elevated commands essentially. You could still save a shortcut to a batch file and give some hot keys or whatever to with these solutions if you want. Perhaps there may be a much simpler method you could use but to me this seems rather simple and I've already tied the pieces together for you so maybe you can use one of these methods

Comment: You can obviously mix and match the commands accordingly for whatever your needs are but I have each method in separate sections plus some reading resources below. Glad to help further or answer further questions if you have any too.

Comment: I've tried this and it didnt do what I wanted so I'll try and add more details to the question

Comment: @Ross So you've tried it via these methods along and NOT by right-click and running as administrator, right? If so, yes, add more detail so I can do further testing to see what the issue may be.

Comment: yes - I tried the above using both a CMD prompt elevated with right click and another without - neither seemed to affect the alternate UAC start type - But I am trying various tests at the moment and it may be user error

Comment: Ok yes it does do what I asked  - I confused myself by trying to run the files on the SUBST drive - which had not yet been subst in the security level